# Cannot find com.adobe.fdf.FDFDoc for Maven

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

I searched everywhere and I cannot seem to be able to find `maven` `Dependencies` artifact for `com.adobe.fdf`

I am working on a very old project and am importing `com.adobe.fdf.FDFDoc`

Does anyone know what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not available within a public Maven repository - maybe because of the license. You have to download it from the [Adobe website](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/fdftoolkit.html) and install it by yourself at your local Maven repository.

Please see the maven-install-plugin: Goal [install-file](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html)